# References for use of symplectic geometry in statistics?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, references, information-geometry

I have heard that many problems in Mathematical Statistics can be stated and solved in terms of Symplectic Geometry. Unfortunately this was a pretty vague statement and I am interested in something more concrete. Also there seem to be some books written form this perspective, but I couldn't find any.

Comment: Where did you hear this statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know nothing whatsoever about symplectic geometry, but a bit of googling brought up a [1997 article in the *Journal of Statistical Planning & Inference* by Barndorff-Nielsen & Jupp](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0378-3758%2897%2900006-2), which contains this quote:

> Some other links between statistics and symplectic geometry have been discussed
>   by Friedrich and Nakamura. Friedrich (1991) established some connections between
>   expected (Fisher) information and symplectic structures. However, his approach and
>   results are quite different from those considered here. Nakamura (1993, 1994) has
>   shown that certain parametric statistical models in which the parameter space *M* is an
>   even-dimensional vector space (and so has the symplectic structure of the cotangent
>   space of a vector space) give rise to completely integrable Hamiltonian systems on *M*.

The cited refs are:

- Friedrich, T., 1991. Die Fisher-lnformation und symplectische Strukturen. *Math. Nachr.* 153: 273-296.
- Nakamura, Y., 1993. Completely integrable gradient systems on the manifolds of Gaussian and multinomial
  distributions. *Japan. J. Ind. Appl. Math.* 10: 179-189.
- Nakamura, Y., 1994. Gradient systems associated with probability distributions. Japan. *J. Ind. Appl. Math.* 11: 21-30.

The article's Introduction says B-N & others have used ***differential* geometry** as an approach to statistical asymptotics. Symplectic geometry is a branch of differential geometry ([according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_geometry)). A [Google Books search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?tbs=bks%3A1&q=%22differential+geometry%22+statistics+OR+statistical+-mechanics+-thermodynamics) finds several books about the application of *differential geometry* to statistics and related fields such as econometrics.

Comment: +1 Good finds.  However, most of the differential geometry applications to statistics do not use symplectic geometry.  I think our difficulty in finding references is testimony to how obscure and rare are the applications of symplectic geometry to statistics.

Answer (score 6):

A direct connection would be unexpected: the two fields appear to have little in common.  For example, [a modern introduction to symplectic geometry published by the American Mathematical Society](http://loveguests.com/books/science/mathematics-statistics/3103-an-introduction-to-symplectic-geometry.html) appears to make no mention of mathematical statistics at all.

At best it seems any connection would come through mathematical physics.  A symplectic geometry on phase space naturally arises in the [Hamiltonian formulation of classical mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics#Geometry_of_Hamiltonian_systems) and that in turn can be used to explore global properties of physical systems.  The study of periodic and near-periodic orbits becomes somewhat statistical (*e.g.*, [ergodic theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_theory)).  When applied to a system with many degrees of freedom it would conceivably relate some aspects of symplectic geometry to thermodynamics, which is inherently a statistical theory

Answer (score 1):

Symplectic model of Statistical Physics and Information Geometry is given by Souriau model of "Lie groups Thermodynamics":
[Lie Group Cohomology and (Multi)Symplectic Integrators: New Geometric Tools for Lie Group Machine Learning Based on Souriau Geometric Statistical Mechanics](https://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/22/5/498),
[Lie Group Statistics and Lie Group Machine Learning Based on Souriau Lie Groups Thermodynamics & Koszul-Souriau-Fisher Metric: New Entropy Definition as Generalized Casimir Invariant Function in Coadjoint Representation](https://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/22/6/642),
(Souriau-Casimir
Lie Groups Thermodynamics
& Machine Learning: A slide presentation)(https://franknielsen.github.io/SPIG-LesHouches2020/Barbaresco-SPILG2020.pdf),
[the youtube version](https://youtu.be/IHupvkGDqeE)

Comment: please add references for your links in case they die in the future